# Как сделать одинаковые flex блоки по ширине и сделать между ними отступы , calc (33.33 - 30px) не работает?

Tags: css, flexbox

Нужно распределить пространство между блоками добавив туда маржу.. как это сделать с помощью функции calc или как то по другому, чтобы в ручную не высчитывать процентное соотношение margin, не используя no-wrap

```
<body>
  <div class = "container">
    <div class = "common first"> 1</div>
    <div class = "common second"> 2</div>
     <div class = "common third"> 3</div>
  </div>
</body>
```

```
*{
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.container{
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.common{
  border: 2px solid tomato;
 flex: 0 1 calc(33.33%-30px); КАЛК НЕ РАБОТАЕТ И ВСЕ ЛОМАЕТ КОГДА ОТНИМАЕШЬ 30px!!!!!!
  margin-right: 30px;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Все работает, только пишите правильно. В `calc` знаки математических операций `+` и `-` нужно экранировать пробелами, т.е. `calc(33.33% - 30px)`.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.common {
  border: 2px solid tomato;
  flex: 0 1 calc(33.33% - 30px);
  margin-right: 30px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="common first"> 1</div>
  <div class="common second"> 2</div>
  <div class="common third"> 3</div>
</div>
```

Только верноятно вы не такого эффекта ожидали - у последнего блока не должно быть отступа справа, так?

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.common {
  border: 2px solid tomato;
  flex: 0 1 calc((100% - 2 * 30px) / 3);
}

.common:not(:last-child) {
  margin-right: 30px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="common first"> 1</div>
  <div class="common second"> 2</div>
  <div class="common third"> 3</div>
</div>
```

Но лучше воспользоваться встроенным во `flex` механизмом отступов:

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  gap: 30px;
}

.common {
  border: 2px solid tomato;
  flex: 0 1 calc((100% - 2 * 30px) / 3);
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="common first"> 1</div>
  <div class="common second"> 2</div>
  <div class="common third"> 3</div>
</div>
```

Comment: спасибо, это то что надо!